# Get call on errors on top level?

Tags: r, error-handling

When I use `tryCatch`, I can define an error handler and use `conditionCall` to determine the call that caused the error. For instance,

```
tryCatch(
    eval(parse(text="prnit('Hello')")),
    error=function(e) {
      cl <- conditionCall(e)
      #...
    })
```

Can I get to the bad call on the R prompt? Until now, I found only this solution:

```
> err_hdl  <- function() {
    file1 <- tempfile("Rrawhist")
    savehistory(file1)
    rawhist <- readLines(file1)
    unlink(file1)

    cat("Error : ", tail(rawhist,1), "\n")
    return(TRUE)    
}
> options(error=err_hdl)
> prnit("Hello")
```

but I believe there must be a more straightforward way..

Any hint appreciated!

I put out a bounty. The first answer that implements the behaviour of the `err_hdl` function above without file I/O that is platform independent will be accepted.

Edit -- the code above seems only to work on windows. I am looking for the input that raised the error.

Comment: There is no error in the first example.

Comment: You meant something more like this in the first example, right?  `tryCatch(
    eval(parse(text=prnit('Hello'))),
    error=function(e) {conditionCall(e)})`

Comment: @Josh O'Brien Yes, you are right. Changed the question.

Comment: @kohske the problem is I can not use `tryCatch` for commands I enter in the R console. I am looking for a custom error catching mechanism for the interactive session.

Comment: FWIW, regarding your edit, the `err_hdl` function should be platform independent as the 1st 4 lines of your `err_hdl` function are the same as the 1st 4 lines in the `history` function.

Comment: @GSee, on my Mac, `history`, as `err_hdl` above, only appears to produce anything useful using R from the terminal. Using the GUI, the two functions produce nothing.

Comment: @BenBarnes Oh. people use the GUI?! ;-)  I tried out the GUI and I see that  `history()` does not appear to work at all!!! I'll look through the docs again, but that sure looks like a bug to me.

Comment: I guess history is just different for R.app. http://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/RMacOSX-FAQ.html#History

Comment: Here is a [link to a more pertinent section of R for Mac OS FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/RMacOSX-FAQ.html#Why-is-the-GUI-not-saving-my-history_003f)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `dump.frames` can be told not to dump to a file but rather to an object in the `.GlobalEnv`. However, I haven't tested it on anything but a Mac. Would the following help?

```
err_hdl2 <- function() {
  dump.frames("theErr", to.file = FALSE)
  cat("What happened?\n", attr(theErr,"error.message"), "\nOh.\n")
}
options(error = err_hdl2)

> prnit(dt)
Error: could not find function "prnit"
What happened?
 Error: could not find function "prnit"

Oh.
```

There might be a drawback to creating the object `theErr` in the global environment, I suppose.

```
> theErr
$`function () 
{
    dump.frames("theErr", to.file = FALSE)
    cat("What`
<environment: 0x1030fe140>

attr(,"error.message")
[1] "Error: could not find function \"prnit\"\n"
attr(,"class")
[1] "dump.frames"
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint to `dump.frames`, this is a new function to me. Can I get to the input that caused the error, i.e. in the example the input `prnit(dt)`?

Comment: @KarstenW., I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "get to". What would you like to do with `prnit(dt)`?

Comment: Ah, is it that the error message is only returning the function it couldn't find instead of the full line of code that produced it?

Comment: @KarstenW., I think I see what you mean, but since `tail(rawhist,1)` in your example isn't returning anything meaningful on this machine, it's still a guess. I'll see if I can make headway tomorrow.

Comment: @KarstenW., unfortunately no progress to report, except that adding a task callback to save the last expression entered by the user such as described [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2009-August/206768.html) does not appear to save the expression that produces an error. But you probably found that out already.

Comment: Well sometimes the answer is "No way." Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: @KarstenW. It sure does look that way. It's frustrating, because the history is clearly available to a running R process (via `savehistory` *or* by typing the up-arrow or `Ctrl-P` or the equivalent), but doesn't seem to be retrievable programatically without writing it to a file. I'm a bit curious whether a C-programmer could use a call to `.Internal()` or some such to access the history more directly, and may try to formulate that as a question, when I have a moment. In any case, thanks for the interesting question!

Comment: @KarstenW., as Josh suggests, someone well versed in C and the R source code might be better able to create a solution. `savehistory` invokes the C function `do_savehistory`, as you can see by examining the ./src/main/names.c file in the R source code. Beyond that, there are the files in the ./src/gnuwin32/getline directory that might also provide insight.